# Trouble with first part of Experiment 11 (Make: Electronics) when using multimeter

Tags: capacitor

Here is my circuit. It works well, as described in a book, but I want to understand it better, so I want to check voltage on capacitor. But when I do it, LED doesn't blink and voltage goes up to 4V. When I turn off multimeter - it works again. Мultimeter is connected to capacitor directly. What did I do wrong?

[image: circuit]

Comment: Is this an analog multimeter or a digital one?

Comment: If it goes up to 4V, input impedance of the multimeter is 1 MOhm, it is a digital one. You should try with another multimeter, a better one.

Comment: 1Mohm is a bit low for a DMM.

Comment: Try using a scope.

Comment: To understand simple circuits I always recommend using a simulator; it rarely suffers from similar issues.

Comment: related: [Why can a voltmeter still measure potential difference if it has a (theoretically) infinite resistance?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/140554/17608)

Comment: @PlasmaHH which one do you use?

Comment: @RogerC. which one? How can I know input impedance before buying?

Comment: @Ishayahu, you can look its datasheet in internet before buying. For example UT61 is a rather low cost DMM, you can read its datasheet in http://uni-trend.com/manual2/UT61English.pdf . Its input impedance is 10 M\$\Omega \$ (page 17).

Comment: @Ishayahu: ltspice; search on this site, there is a question with lists of possible simulators to try as answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously your multimeter influences your circuit. To measure the voltage across the capacitor some current must flow through the multimeter. The amount of current through the multimeter is defined by the measured voltage and the [internal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter#Sensitivity_and_input_impedance) of the multimeter.

With the high resistor value of \$470 K\Omega\$ even an internal resistance as high as \$1 M\Omega\$ has a remarkable impact on your circuit.

When you have the parts at hand, you could change your circuit to use \$47 K\Omega\$ and \$22 \mu F\$. The time from flash to flash shouldn't change. However the flash duration would be 10 times longer.

Comment: Another quick solution could be to swap 15k and 27k resistors, maybe voltage is not enough to light the LED though

Comment: It doesn't work for me, because of transistor. The LED lights without blink(
If I understand right, the voltage on capacitor in my case is only 2V?

Comment: @Ishayahu - Transistor??? We are talking about a thyristor. Where do you have the 2V from??? What have you exactly done that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Kitana sotty, thyristor) I use multimeter to measure voltage on capacitor. In that case LED doesn't blink and I don't understand why